# why is jvm throwing "unrecognized option" when i use "-d64"?

Tags: batch-file, jvm, cygwin

I'm setting up my JAVA_OPTS with: "-d64 -server -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled" and then some.

I thought the -d64 was to specify that the machine was 64bit or running on 64bit!?

This seems to work fine on Macs. When I tried it on Windows 7 using Cygwin to run the shell script, it breaks. If I remove the -d64, everything works fine.

I also did the same thing using windows batch files, the -d64 still throw the same error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-d64` option is Solaris/Linux specific.  On Windows that option is [not available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

As Mac OsX is linux-based, the option would work there.  On Windows you will need to select the JVM by selecting the executable (the 64 bit/32 bit versions are separate installation) -- either directly naming the executable or by properly adding its bin to the PATH environmental variable

Comment: `-d64` doesn't work on macOS or anymore: `Unrecognized option: -d64
jvm 1    | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
jvm 1    | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`